# Is there a way to update Xcode version through script with terminal?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

I have a lot of OSX machine in my system. When Xcode has new version, I have to update Xcode version in each machine one by one (with manual way).

So I would like to know that Is there a way to update Xcode version through script with terminal? Then I could run only one script to update all machines in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo softwareupdate --install Xcode` for the current App Store version.

Comment: But pay attention it's only for update, not for new installation.